# Using a function twice using map

Tags: function, haskell, dictionary, functional-programming

I want a function used twice on a String. I'm gonna explain what i want so I hope at the end of the question you get what i mean.

So i have this function.

```
foo :: String -> [String]
foo = ...
```

Now i want that this function is used twice on a String. So when used first it should run foo with the String that is given to the function and on the second run it should used on every String from the [String] that is produced by the first run. So i guessed that map is the best function to do that.
So i got this function now

```
f :: String -> [String]
f w = map foo (foo w)
```

But the compliler gives me this error:

```
MyHaskell.hs:86:19:
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
Expected type: String -> String
  Actual type: String -> [String]
In the first argument of `map', namely `edits1'
In the expression: map edits1 (edits1 word)
```

I guess the problem is that my function foo (String -> [String]) does not work out with map ((a->b) -> [a] -> [b]).

How do i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@alternative brought me to this answer.

I have to concat the result so i'll get [String] as a result.

```
f :: String -> [String]
f w = concat (map foo (foo w))
```

Comment: Which is equal to `import Control.Monad; f = foo >=> foo`.

Comment: also the same as `concatMap foo . foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close.

```
f :: String -> [[String]]
f w = map foo (foo w)
```

You just got the type signature wrong - if you are applying `foo` to each element, each element becomes a `[String]` so you need a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter, but same thing:

`double_map2 f g xs = map (f . g) xs`